# Do filenames add to the filesize?

Tags: storage, disk-space, filenames

For example, let say a Unicode character would take up 1 byte. So we have a text file that is named `foo`.
The contents is

```
foo
bar
```

Remember to include the return carriage (It is a control character I think, but it still takes up 1 byte).
Therefore this text file named `foo` has a file size of 7 bytes. Now does the filename contribute/adds to the file size? If it does, then the file size would be 10 bytes. Otherwise, it is 7 bytes.
The file system is NTFS.

Comment: A reasonable research effort is to create such file and check its size reported by the OS. Try this in many different filesystems and draw conclusions. Have you tried with at least one filesystem type?

Comment: "NTFS directories are BTrees with data in both the interior and leaf nodes... [T]he full text of the filename is stored in the nodes," https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349455/does-the-length-of-a-file-name-impact-huge-ntfs-folder-indexes A path in NTFS can be 32,767 bytes, which should have a noticeable effect for a long filename. Your mileage may vary with other FS, e.g. ext*n*, FAT32...

Answer (score 3):

No, they don't.

File names are metadata, and do not appear in the file itself.